# Using DFS-R instead of mirroring on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-mirroring

I want to do mirroring on SQL Server. While mirroring is better, only Enterprise can do this and the licence cost is an issue. I can use SQL Server standard which allows DFS-Replication not mirroring.

As I need 2 SQL Servers - main and backup - and only one database on them - what would stop me using DFS-R as a solution? Can the database files be too large for DFS-R?

Comment: No, all editions can do mirroring. Besides, mirroring is an *older* technology replaced by availability groups. Those can be used in the Standard edition as well. And **No**, you can't use file system replication. You'll end up with a corrupt replica. You can't just replicate data pages, you need the corresponding log entries as well. If you don't *guarantee* all matching pages are replicated, the copy will be useless and unrecoverable

Comment: I have never heard of anyone using DFSR to replicate SQL Server data and log files. It just sounds like a risky endeavor full of pitfalls.

Comment: @RossBush have you heard about companies that lost their backup servers, or tried to fail over to their "replicas" and found them unusable? That's what happens when you try to use file system snapshots without ensuring you mirror the *entire storage*. Which of course, is expensive and requires specialized hardware, software and administration, far more expensive than setting up a cluster or an AG. **AND** the replication software needs to understand about database transactions, to avoid copying data pages out of sync

Comment: ok. So standard supports mirroring?

Answer (score 1):

Mirroring is deprecated.  You don't want to use it.

Standard Edition supports

[Basic Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=A%20basic%20availability%20group%20supports%20a%20failover%20environment,basic%20availability%20groups%20are%20summarized%20in%20this%20document.)

> Always On Basic Availability Groups provide a high availability solution for SQL Server from version 2016 and above on Standard Edition.

which are the replacement for Database Mirroring on Standard Edition.  Or you can use

[Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

> SQL Server Log shipping allows you to automatically send transaction log backups from a primary database on a primary server instance to one or more secondary databases on separate secondary server instances.